# Does array length plays any role while finding a duplicate element in array of numbers?

Tags: java

```
public static int findDuplicate(int[] arr) {
    
    int n = arr.length-2;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : arr){
        sum+=i;
    }
    
    return (sum - ((n*(n+1))/2));
}
```

Here is the code. This code must return any duplicate element present in the array. Say, if array is { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 } then it must return 1. It works fine for the test cases but I just want to understand the role of `arr.length-2` used here.

Sample input
5 size
1 2 3 4 1
Sample output :
1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is based on assumption that your array **must contain**

- *all* numbers from `0` till "*some*" `N`, like `0, 1, 2, 3, .. , N` (in any order)
- *one* extra number `X` (*can* be duplicate of other numbers, but *doesn't need to* be)

How many numbers are there in array?

- `0 ... N` gives us `N+1` numbers
- `X` is `1` number.

So we have `N+1` + `1` which is `N+2` numbers.

In other words array has `N+2` numbers, which means `N+2 = array.length`.

#### **And that means `N = array.length - 2`**

(we will need that later).

---

Now sum of all numbers stored in array is `0 + 1 + 2 + ... + N` + `X` (their order doesn't matter).

We can get rid of `0` since it doesn't affect our sum, which gives us

```
SUM = 1 + 2 + ... + N + X
```

We can also replace `1 + 2 + ... + N` part with `N*(N+1)/2` based on formula on sum of [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

This leaves us with

```
SUM = N*(N+1)/2 + X
```

Based on above the duplicate element `X` is `X = SUM - N*(N+1)/2` where `N = array.length-2`.